# Image not showing in Drupal 7

Tags: uri

Site is hosted in fasthosts wherein `<IfModule>`  is not supported so they advice me to edit `.htaccess` to something like this.

```
Comment, 
Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
Options –Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php
Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A1209600
ExpiresByType text/html A1
```

Sample:

```
#<FilesMatch
#"\.(engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|svn-base)$|^(code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Ta
#g|Template|all-wcprops|entries|format)$">
# Order allow,deny
#</FilesMatch>
```

It solved my first issue, 500 error.

This time, another error is showing, images are not correctly showing and css.
Instead of the path to be `site.com/drupal installation/` image of path, image address become `site.com/image of path`.

By the way, I am installing drupal in a sub folder. `site.com/dupalHere`

Comment: If you could post **all** current content of your `.htaccess` file, it would be much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add line

```
RewriteBase /dupalHere
```

to your `.htaccess` file.